# What is the real source of these stotram or sloka?

Tags: saraswati

1. “ওঁ পূর্ণ পরমজ্যোতি...”
   OM PURNA PARAMJYOTI...
2. সায়াহ্নে সরস্বতী রবিমণ্ডল মধ্যস্থা শুক্লবর্ণা দ্বিভূজা
   ত্রিশূলডম্বরু করাবৃযতাসনারূঢ়া বৃদ্ধা রুদ্রানী রুদ্রদৈবতা
   সামবেদোদাহৃতা ধ্যেয়।
   SAYAHNE SARASWATI RAVIMANDAL MADYASTHA SUKLAVARNA DVIBHUJA
   TRISULDAMBRU KARABRITASANARUDHA BRIDDHA RUDRANI RUDRADAIVATA 
   SAMVEDADAHRITA DHYAYA
   ওঁ আয়াহি বরদে দেবি এয়ক্ষরে ব্রহ্ম বাদিনি।
   গায়ত্রী ছন্দসাং মাত: ব্রহ্ম যোনি নমোহস্তুতে।
   OM AYAHI VARADE DEVI EYAKSHARE BRAHMA VADINI
   GAYATRI CHANDASANG MATAH BRAHMA YONI NAMAHSTUTE
   ওঁ বরদে দেবি পরমজ্যোতি: ব্রহ্মাণে স্বাহা।
   OM VARADE DEVI PARAMJYOTIH BRAHMANE SVAHA